# Reference request: About Weil book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

In "Standard conjectures on algebraic cycles" of Grothendieck and "Algebraic cycles and the Weil conjectures" of Kleiman they say in their references:

> A. Weil: *Variétés Kählériennes*, Hermann, Paris, 1968.

They refer to:

> A. Weil: *Introduction à l’étude des variétés kählériennes*, Hermann, Paris. ?

Comment: Yes, but there have been two printings, the original one  from 1958, the second in 1971 . I don't think there is a printing dated 1968

Comment: Any further questions? or are you satisfied with the information you have received?

Comment: Are you still there?

Answer (score 2):

Probably. Math Reviews shows

Weil, André, Introduction à l'étude des variétés kählériennes. (French) Publications de l'Institut de Mathématique de l'Université de Nancago, VI. Actualités Sci. Ind. no. 1267 Hermann, Paris 1958 175 pp. MR0111056 (Reviewer: F. Hirzebruch)

It doesn't show any 1968 publication by Weil with "kählériennes" in the title.